# How to run a standard chunk of code from inside a controller/model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 'chunk of code' that performs calculations on data and updates some tables based on those calculations.

I'd like to be able to reference that chunk of code from multiple locations, something like this:

```
# from controller or model
def ...
  ...
  run `chunk of code`
  ...
end
```

This is an inordinately simple question - where would `chunk of code` go and how would I get Rails to run it from controller/model?

Answer (score 1):

Calculations or table updates belongs to a model, so what about defining some new class method in your model, e.g.

```
def self.calculate
  ...
  chunk of code
  ...
end
```

it can be then called from both model and controller

Comment: How is it called? can you literally just write `self.calculate`?

Comment: I tried `self.calculate` but I couldn't call it from the model. Defining `calculate` instead did work, see my answer above.

Comment: no, self.method_name means class method (like static methods in Java), you can call it via Model.calculate. E.g. if you have model Car, and in this model self.calculate is defined, then you can call Car.calculate almost from anywhere... If you define calculate method without self keyword, its object's method, not class... Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I managed it by doing:

```
def calculate
   chunk of code
end
```

Then to call it from the model/controller:

```
def some_other_action
  ...
  @record.calculate (or self.calculate in model)
  ...
end
```